# Android : why is my string variable not recognised outside my try - catch block?

Tags: android, try-catch

When I print `getCategory` in Logcat with the code below I get `the category is Plumber` (or whatever `review.setCategory` is set to.)

```
  //post the review that has been clicked in the ListView and send it to
        // ContactView.php and from that get other review details
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, ContactView_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //hide the 'loading' box when the page loads
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        //toast the response of ContactView.php, which has been converted to a
                        //JSON array in the Php file with JSON encode
                        Toast.makeText(ContactView.this, response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            getCategory = null;
                            try {
                                JSONArray responseObject = new JSONArray(response);
                                JSONObject obj = responseObject.getJSONObject(i);
                                Review review = new Review();
                                review.setCategory(obj.getString("category"));
                                review.setName(obj.getString("name"));
                                review.setPhone(obj.getString("phone"));
                                review.setAddress(obj.getString("address"));
                                review.setComment(obj.getString("comment"));
                                //we are getting the review id so we can pull extra needed info, like Address etc
                                //review.setReviewid(obj.getString("reviewid"));
                                Toast.makeText(ContactView.this, review.getCategory(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                //reviewList.add(review);

                                getCategory = review.getCategory();
                                System.out.println("the category is " + getCategory);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
                                // Do something to recover ... or kill the app.
                            }

                        }
```

But when I put the `System.out.println("the category is " + getCategory);` anywhere else in the activity, outside the `try-catch`, I get `the category is null`

I read many posts on Stackoverflow to solve this by declaring `getCategory = null;` before the `try-catch` block but t doesn't solve it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the type of `getCategory`

in the example below you can access `name` that was set inside of the `try`

```
String name = "";

try{

    name = "asdasd";

}catch (Exception e){

}

System.out.println(name);
```

Comment: He *is* setting `getCategory`.  The problem is that the `try` block can `throw` before `getCategory` is set.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I would then suggest before the try catch, instead of setting it to null. Set a default category

Comment: @Derek Can you explain what you mean by a default category?

Comment: @CHarris Well if it's simply a string I would default the category to "none". Then it would read, `The category is none`